Forceing language of SKStoreReviewController.requestReview() pop-up
My application is not using any Localizable for now. It only supports Turkish. When trying to show SKStoreReviewController's Review popup, it is only presented in the same language as the device. Is there any possible way to present it in a different language?
PS: I tried to update Userdefaults "AppleLanguages" but it has no effect.
